# UIActionSheet making multiple UIButton changes

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, uiactionsheet

I have 6 UIbuttons on a view. I am trying to call a UIActionSheet for each button, and change the buttons image and a UIlabel. I can get the first one to work as desired. I can't seem to get the second to make the changes like the first. 
Here is my code. please help.

```
-(IBAction)lifeStatus:(id)sender {

    UIActionSheet *lifeStatus = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Select" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"UNSECURED" otherButtonTitles:@"SECURED", @"PENDING", nil];


    lifeStatus.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
    [lifeStatus showInView:self.view.window];
    [lifeStatus release];

}
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)lifeStatus clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger) buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        self.lifeLabel.text = @"UNSECURED";
        [self.lifeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RedButton.png"] forState:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        self.lifeLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        self.lifeLabel.text = @"SECURED";
        [self.lifeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GreenButton.png"] forState:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        self.lifeLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } else if (buttonIndex == 2) {
        self.lifeLabel.text = @"PENDING";
        [self.lifeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YellowButton.png"] forState:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        self.lifeLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
}

-(IBAction)sceneStatus:(id)sender {

    UIActionSheet *sceneStatus = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Select" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"UNSECURED" otherButtonTitles:@"SECURED", @"PENDING", nil];

    sceneStatus.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
    [sceneStatus showInView:self.view.window];
    [sceneStatus release];

}

-(void)actionSheet1:(UIActionSheet *)sceneStatus clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        self.sceneLabel.text = @"UNSECURED";
        [self.sceneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RedButton.png"] forState:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        self.sceneLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        self.sceneLabel.text = @"SECURED";
        [self.sceneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GreenButton.png"] forState:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        self.sceneLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } else if (buttonIndex == 2) {
        self.sceneLabel.text = @"PENDING";
        [self.sceneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YellowButton.png"] forState:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        self.sceneLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create UIActionSheet with Default Buttons. On every button tap set the button titles  you need to show in actionSheet.

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:itemText];
} 
actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the formatting, your code is a bit difficult to read but if I understand you correctly, you could try the following.

First, create a selectedButton property or field. Add a target for each button:

```
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownOutside];
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownOutside];
... other buttons ...

-(void)buttonTouched:(id)sender {
    self.selectedButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    //Show UIActionSheet here
    ...
}
```

Then inside your UIActionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex: method, the selectedButton will be pointing towards the correct button, so it should be pretty simple to modify it as needed.

Comment: Where do I add the property or field. Under my .m or .h do I add this to the IBAction of the button under the .m and do I add the void to each button statement? Sorry for the jacked up questions. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can create the field like any other field (i.e. in the interface of the .h). All you need to do is 'selectedButton = (UIButton *)sender;' if the action of the button. You will show the UIActionSheet directly afterward with the clicked button stored in selectedButton.

Comment: If you are setting up the buttons in Interface Builder, yes, you should set the button in the IBAction. You don't need to add void, you can leave it as IBAction.

Comment: I was able to use the .tag, and it solved my problem. Thanks for your time. I'm sure i'll be back.